# How do I connect a VM instance created on google cloud to a vmware workstation instance created on my local system using workstation player?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vmware-workstation, google

I have created a windows server vm instance in google cloud. It is a ADserver. Apart from that; I have created two external windows virtual machines in my local system on vmware workstation player. I want to connect this two vms with the Adserver created on google cloud. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) could have solved your problem but currently GCP does not offer client-to-gateway connections. It only offers gateway-to-gateway connections.